# The workflow sending email to task owner (Send Task notification email) is not succeeding and goes in waiting state for some cases in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

Error Details:

Error while calling OnBeginRequest on WorkflowTransactionContext

Plugin Trace:

[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.Activities.SendEmail]
[SendEmailStep3: Send notification email]

Error Message:

Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Crm.CrmException: Error while calling OnBeginRequest on WorkflowTransactionContext.
at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.SendEmailActivityService.Execute(ActivityContext executionContext, SendEmail sendEmail)
at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
Inner Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName, Boolean shouldReconnect)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
at Microsoft.Crm.CrmDbConnection.StartTransaction(IsolationLevel il)
at Microsoft.Crm.CrmTransaction.StartTransaction(IsolationLevel isoLevel, Boolean verifyIsolationLevelIfTransactionAlreadyStarted)
at Microsoft.Crm.SqlExecutionContext.OnBeginRequest(Boolean startTransaction, IsolationLevel isoLevel, SolutionOperationContext operationContext, Guid solutionId, String workloadGroup)
at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.ExecutionContext.OnBeginRequest(Guid userId, Boolean startTransaction, IsolationLevel isolationLevel, ExecutionOperationContext operationContext, CallerOriginToken originToken)
at Microsoft.Crm.BusinessEntities.ExecutionContext.OnBeginRequest(Guid userId, Boolean startTransaction)
at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.WorkflowTransactionContext.StartTransaction()
at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.WorkflowTransactionContext.OnBeginRequest()
at Microsoft.Crm.Workflow.Services.ActivityServiceBase.ExecuteInTransactedContext(ActivityDelegate activityDelegate)

Comment: You must provide more detail about problem. it's just call stack

Comment: I have configured one asyn workflow to send email notification to task owner but some of the workflows are in waiting state.

Comment: "New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session" seems more than one backend job runs at the same time on the same record.